# Image inside FrameLayout not shrinking though scaletype set to fitcenter

Tags: android, android-framelayout, scaletype

I have an `ImageView` that must be wrapped inside `Framelayout`. But when I use `FrameLayout`, the image is clipped within the bounds of the `ImageView` and not made "fit" even if I use `setScaleType(ScaleType.FitCenter); but when I use other`ViewGroup`such as`RelativeLayout`, the result is ok. why? what can I do? Here is my code:

```
    FrameLayout profileimage_fl = new FrameLayout(
            getSherlockActivity());
    layoutWidth = WindowSize.convertedHeight(150);
    layoutHeight = WindowSize.convertedHeight(150);
    p_ll = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(layoutWidth, layoutHeight);
    leftMargin = WindowSize.convertedWidth(1);
    topMargin = WindowSize.convertedHeight(1);
    rightMargin = WindowSize.convertedWidth(1);
    bottomMargin = WindowSize.convertedHeight(1);
    p_ll.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);
    profileimage_fl.setLayoutParams(p_ll);
    profileimage_fl.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);

    ImageView profileimage = new ImageView(getSherlockActivity());
    layoutWidth = WindowSize.convertedHeight(150);
    layoutHeight = WindowSize.convertedHeight(150);
    p_fl = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(layoutWidth, layoutHeight);
    profileimage.setLayoutParams(p_fl);
    profileimage.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    profileimage.setPadding(WindowSize.convertedWidth(0),
            WindowSize.convertedHeight(0), WindowSize.convertedHeight(0),
            WindowSize.convertedWidth(0));

    profileimage_fl.addView(profileimage);
```

then I add `profileimage_fl` to a viewgroup that I inflated in a layout. That layout xml contains only that viewgroup. You see, I don't usually use xml.

Comment: What size is your FrameLayout? match_parent, wrap_content, fixed size?

Comment: I forgot to mention that my FrameLayout is fixed size. Sorry

Comment: can you post your layout xml?

Comment: I would recommend you to create the layout exactly as you want in xml. Once created, you can code it. It will give you speed and the certainty that what your code is gonna achieve is gonna look correct (images, frame layouts, etc).